# Converting mosaic dataset to TIN gives error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, convert, 3d-analyst, tin

I merged several DEMs together in on single DEM with mosaic dataset. 
Now I wanted to convert this mosaic dataset in Vector with TIN. But when I use the tool (3D Analyst Tool) Raster to TIN comes an Error...

Have I to convert the mosaic Dataset first to another format? (How?)

Or do you have any other ideas to convert mosaic dataset to vector?

Comment: What error do you encounter?

Comment: Has anyone figured this out yet?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what error you get but the most common error with converting Raster to TIN is that the **"Maximum Number Points" optional limit has been reached**.  Although this is an optional parameter it is set to 1500000 by default.

Delete this limit, leaving the field blank, and try again.

Comment: No also this doesn`t work! I get every time the message: "In the background processing a fatal error has occurred, so that they can not be continued.
The background events were due to an error can not be completed." :(

Comment: The Error in results is: Raster to TIN [000000_12301899]

Comment: Error may occure due the Extent or Cellsize inconsistancy. What is the Error number in Results window?